# Redirect search traffic to mobile page

Tags: mobile, google

For my arcade website I made a tablet website (t.example.com)

The flash games on my normal website (example.com) don't work on tablets.

On the tablet website I publish HTML5 games that do work.

I build a mobile redirect so all tablet users are redirected to t.example.com

Now when sombody find my website trough Google on pacman games. The url redirects from example.com/pacman/ to t.example.com

My question is:
 - Is this the right way to do it since the users can't play on the normal site?
 - Do I risk a Google penaly or drop in results because I redirect to another url?

Comment: How are you handling the redirect, and how are you determining what a "tablet" is defined by?

Comment: One question for you, are you using the standard m.[SLD].[TLD] format for the mobile (or should I say tablet) website, or are you actually using t.[SLD].[TLD] . This has no bearing on the question; I am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows you to maintain separate sites for different devices and redirect between them without penalty.

Normally, you would redirect from the page on the desktop site deep into the same content on the site for the correct device.  Since your content is device dependent, that sounds like it might not be possible.  Even so, it will probably frustrate your users to get redirected to home page of your tablet site.  It would be better for users if you could redirect from a desktop Pacman game to a tablet Pacman game.  I realize that there are many flash games that have no tablet version.  In those cases, I would recommend redirecting to a list of games in the category.  For example from "Roger's Supreme Shoot-em-up" you could redirect to a list of shooter games for the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your main URL (example.com) the only entry way to your site. You can query the device being used to access the site and then redirect to the (t.example.com) if the user is using a tablet.

Do you know how many of your users are google redirects?

Comment: If you want search engine traffic, you have to allow search engines to index your content deeply and send traffic to deep pages.   If a user searches for "Pacman", the user isn't going to be happy landing on a page that doesn't have a Pacman game (such as your home page).   Google always tries to give the user the most relevant landing page on your site possible.